# How can I use json on localhost (MAMP)?

Tags: php, json, ajax, localhost, mamp

index.php

```
    <button class="button">color</button>
    <div class="blue"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
```

script.js

```
$(".button").click(function(){
  $.ajax({
        url: "update.php",
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            $(".blue").html(data.blue);
            $(".red").html(data.red);
              alert("success");
        }
    })
});
```

update.php

```
$array['blue'] = "blue content";
$array['red'] = "red content";
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($array);
```

I want to work with json on localhost. But it is not working.
I am using MAMP.

Comment: what error you are getting @Jarla ?

Comment: you don't need to use header('Content-type: application/json'); in update.php and in ajax u need to use JSON.parse(data) before using the data values

Comment: Which errors/exceptions do you get?

Comment: @Sander Visser I do not get a success alert. Actually nothing is happening when I click the button

Comment: @vSugumar You do need the application/json content-type because the application serves json. It wouldn't make sense to remove it

Comment: Check the network panel for that XHR request. See what its sending/receiving.

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ what is a XHR request?

Comment: @SanderVisser How can I receive the exact errors you need?

Comment: *"XMLHttpRequest (XHR) is an API in the form of an object whose methods transfer data between a web browser and a web server. The object is provided by the browser's JavaScript environment."* Check the network panel after you click the button in the developer console.

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ I checked in the console but there is no error

Comment: In your browser press `ctrl+shift+j` you get a console. then right click and select the `Log**Request` then press the button. You should see the request. (chrome)

Comment: No, but there is a network panel where you can view XHR requests. http://i.imgur.com/fJahdGm.png (chrome example)

Comment: @SanderVisser I posted all my errors in my question. But this error is something else. Has nothing to do with this specific code

Comment: Do you even have jQuery referenced in your project? Is it included?

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ Yes I am using jquery-2.2.3

Comment: So don't think think the reason is the localhost?

Comment: What is `project.php`? What is around line 463?

Comment: project.php is actually index.php in my question. I renamed it to make the question simple

Comment: The error around line 463 is something different. Has nothing to do with this problem

Comment: Can you post the reason for the downvote? Just for learning

Comment: I think it was downvoted because the question doesn't contain the errors ;). It's hard to help without a clear exception.

Comment: @Jarla hope you have included jQuery. I replicated exactly everything else in my local and its working as expected.

Comment: what errors do u get on the console?

Comment: @Jarla on your revision history there's a refernce error `$` not found meaning u did not include jquery

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile But all other jQuery is working

Comment: Are u sure u don't have any errors? can u try my answer below @Jarla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `DataType : 'json'` on the ajax call and set `encode` to `true`. I have done a working fiddle for you to see, that is working.

```js
  $(document).on("click", ".send", function (event) {
   $.ajax({
            url: "http://www.personaldev.co.za/json/update.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType : 'json',
            encode : true,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                $(".blue").html(data.blue);
                $(".red").html(data.red);
            }
        })
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 

<button class="send">Send</button>
<div class="blue" style="background: blue;color: white"></div>
<div class="red" style="background: red;color:white"></div>
```

**update.php**

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    $array['blue'] = "blue content";
    $array['red'] = "red content";

    echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

Nb: `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` you don't actually need this I did this so that the fiddle can be able to access the update file from my server, so you can see this in action live.

result :

[image]

Comment: It is not working on my page. Maybe because I am on localhost?

Comment: I also did that on localhost.. check the console it should print something

Comment: console not printing out anything

Comment: that is strange, can u run the code snippet above, u will see its working as u desired

Comment: yeah I know, that is bad luck

Comment: Is the "integrity" in the jQuery link important?

Comment: The integrity and crossorigin attributes are used for Subresource Integrity (SRI) checking. This allows browsers to ensure that resources hosted on third-party servers have not been tampered with. Use of SRI is recommended as a best-practice, whenever libraries are loaded from a third-party source.

Comment: The ajax request is only working if I remove these lines `dataType : 'json', encode : true,` and add this line `$(".red").html(data);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142174/discussion-between-masivuye-cokile-and-jarla).

Comment: do I have to install json on my localhost or something?